# Laravel Schema design many to many

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, oop

hello i'm trying to build school management system on secondary education and i have a ERM design i would Like to ask  does laravel handle this type of relationship **Many to many?** please amend if i'm doing it wrongly since i'm a beginner thanks..

**ERM**[image]

Comment: i'm asking if the way i connected them is it right way? and also does is complicates laravel's way of handling relationship?

Comment: @Grace Laravel's Eloquent model can definitely do many-to-many relationships. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many.

Comment: always use `id` field for your table primary key and lower case for field name, example you have used `Student_ID` in student table, better change it with `id`. Similarly do it for all your tables. Foreign key should be `student_id`

Comment: okay thanks you @rkj how bout the way i structure it is it okay? or do u have any better approach?

Comment: structure is fine, here `connector` table act as pivot table between student and other tables. i am adding laravel model structure in answer, just look that and if you think it will work accordingly you then you can use it

Comment: @rkt thank you sir.. now i shall proceed this to physical and amend it ..

Comment: That is not an ERM, it's an ERD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With 2 db tables many to many reationship

```
students(id,name,created_at,updated_at)
subjects(id, name, created_at,updated_at)
student_subjects(id, student_id, subject_id)
```

> Models

```
class Student extends Model{
     public function subjects(){
         return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class, 'student_subjects'); //here student_subjects is as a pivot table
     }
}

class Subject extends Model{
     public function stdents(){
         return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'student_subjects'); //here student_subjects is as a pivot table
     }
}
```

> Now Save data

```
$student = Student::find(1);
$student->subjects()->attach(2); // it will save subject 2 for student 1 in `student_subjects` table.
```

**Note:** similarly you can create relation for other models

For details check https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @Grace you have lots of foreign keys in connector table, do the all foreign key needed in table. If all the foreign key is not depend on each other then better you separate it. like this `student_subjects`, `student_batches`... pivot tables

Comment: @Grace i have updated answer. let me know if you have any question

Comment: yeah i was thinking of removing some Fk  to save some trouble hehe thank you @ rkj  for helping me